# Application of Central Limit Theorem for nonnegative RV

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Suppse $X_1, X2, \dots$ are iid nonnegative r.v.s with mean 1 and finite variance $\sigma^2>0$.
Show that $2(\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n}) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: What kind of convergence do you mean? I suppose it is meant to be weak convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt n=\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt n}=\color{blue}{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\mathbb E(X_j))}{\sqrt n\sigma}}\color{red}{\frac{\sigma\sqrt n}{\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt n}}.$$
The convergence of the blue term follows from the classical central limit theorem while the red term can be treated with the law of large numbers.

To combine the two results, we will need Slutsky's lemma.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method):

$$2(\sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt{n})
=2\sqrt{n} \left[\sqrt{\frac{S_n}n} - 1
\right]\\
=2\sqrt{n} \left[f\left(\frac{S_n}n\right) - f(1)
\right]
$$with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$
$$
\to 2 f'(1)N(0,\sigma^2)=N(0,\sigma^2)
$$

in distribution.